# Add scroll bar in div inside a table

Tags: css, html, html-table

**index.html**

```
<td>
<div id="wrapper">
words go her alot of them
</div>
</td>
```

**style.css**

```
  #wrapper {
            height: 100%;
            width: 200px;
            overflow: auto;
          }
```

I am currently unable to get the scroll bar to appear, this is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `overflow` property:

```
#wrapper {
   height: 100%;
   width: 200px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

The `overflow` property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.

This property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.

**Note:** The overflow property only works for block elements with a specified height.

**[Further reading - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)**
**[Further reading - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)**

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

> overflow: scroll;

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try setting overflow to scroll:

```
#wrapper {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add a height to the `td` tag;

**Example:**

`height="250px"` or change your height in your `#wrapper.`

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

i used this and it fixed the problem